# Penalty vs. punishment

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Punishment or penalty? which one is more suitable in this context?

> More important than **punishment** / **penalty**, it is really essential to find crimes’ motive to prevent it from happening again.

According to dictionaries, I think that penalty is a kind legal term while punishment is a more general word. But I am curious to know which one is really perfect in the above sentence?

Comment: **The** penalty is a specific punishment. Aside: 'essential' is an absolute so the 'really' need not be there. Aside #2 you either need "find the crime's motive" or "find crimes' motive".

Comment: @WeatherVane and what about "find crimes' motives"? Is it correct?

Comment: That is a different question now, and has been asked before... maybe any one crime has several motives, or more usually a single motive.